azure function runs triggers in parallel?
I'm creating an application that will use Azure Functions combined with Azure Bus Service. The idea is to process the messages from the bus in Azure Functions.
I'm reading the documentation and I want to confirm one thing:
In the Consumption plan, do the instances automatically grow based on the triggers, with a limit of 100 instances? That is, if at any given time 50 messages arrive in my queue, will 50 functions be activated at the same time in parallel?
Thanks

You are right in your understanding, however there are these considerations you should be aware of:

By default, for Service Bus triggers, Azure Functions processes messages one at a time within a single instance. However, you can configure concurrent message processing using the maxConcurrentCalls setting in the host.json file.

The maximum number of instances that can be created is indeed 100 for most regions in the Consumption plan. However:

a) This limit is per function app, not per individual function.
b) Some regions have a lower limit of 60 instances.
c) You can request a higher limit by contacting Azure support.


The scaling is not always instantaneous or on a 1:1 ratio with incoming messages. Azure uses an algorithm to determine when to scale out, considering factors like:

a) The rate of incoming messages
b) How long it takes to process each message
c) Available resources



{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "prefetchCount": 100,
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
        "maxConcurrentCalls": 32,
        "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:05:00"
      }
    }
  }
}

prefetchCount: Determines how many messages the Functions runtime will retrieve in advance
maxConcurrentCalls: Sets the maximum number of messages that can be processed concurrently on a single instance.
maxAutoRenewDuration: Sets the maximum duration within which the message lock will be renewed automatically.

Excellent, thank you very much. Regarding "This limit is per function app, not per individual function" you mean that the Function App can have several functions registered, right?
I have several things to configure, thanks for your help

Just to confirm, when you refer to concurrent message processing, this will allow me to get multiple messages from Azure bus in my Azure function, but the processing will be parallel, right? That is, if I have 5 functions running, each one is running independently.?

When you set maxConcurrentCalls to 10 and Azure Functions scales to 5 instances due to the load, each instance will be capable of handling up to 10 messages concurrently. This means that theoretically, if the load and system conditions allow, up to 50 messages could be processed simultaneously across all instances. This configuration maximizes the parallel processing capability of your function app, potentially improving throughput under high load conditions

I think I understand you now. I think I actually need the default configuration of processing one message per instance, my task involves data processing in Python, so I think it's not possible to handle these tasks concurrently. I just needed it to scale the number of instances based on the number of service bus messages, and as I understand you, this happens by default according to the algorithm you mentioned. Please correct me if I'm wrong on something.
